# Use XMLHttpRequest to read data after a period of time - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to read a text file (on local) after a period of time (after 10s).
After 10s, XMLHttpRequest retrieves the text file but the content (responseText) does not changed even though I have changed it.

Here is my code:

```
var list = [];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        if (xhr.responseText.length == 0) {
            undef();
        }
        else {
            def();
        }
    }
}

getFile();

function getFile() {
    list = [];
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('text/list.txt'), true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

var myVar = setInterval(function(){getFile()}, 10 * 1000);

function def() {
    // do something
}

function undef() {
    // do something
}
```

I don' know why and how to fix it, please help.

Comment: Which OS? It may be relevant.

Comment: Most probably a caching issue. Try to use `chrome.extension.getURL('text/list.txt') + "?" + (new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: cache seems to be the problem but chrome.extension.getURL('text/list.txt') + "?" + (new Date()).getTime() does not fix this. I even try clearing cache but it is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it is that the folder containing the file that I use when coding is different from the folder containing the extension when added to Chrome.
I just modified the wrong file.
Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The fast/lazy solution is to change your link address without changing the file it's accessing.

Modify your link with LinkToFile+"?="+Math.random()

It won't match anything in the cache but it will fetch the same file.